# How to mix two colors at the point of intersection of paths in Coregraphics?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, core-graphics

I need to mix two colors on drawing smooth curves in image view, as in - mixing of red and blue should give purple (red+yellow = orange,yellow+blue=green) only at the point of intersection of two colors. I tried using blending modes of coregraphics but did not work. Can anyone help me out?

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.prePreviousPoint = self.previousPoint;
    self.previousPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint mid1 = [self calculateMidPointForPoint:self.previousPoint andPoint:self.prePreviousPoint];
    CGPoint mid2 = [self calculateMidPointForPoint:currentPoint andPoint:self.previousPoint];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawImageView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [currentColor setStroke];
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);

    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), TRUE);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), TRUE);
    [self.drawImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.drawImageView.frame.size.width, self.drawImageView.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    //    // Use QuadCurve is the key
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, self.previousPoint.x, self.previousPoint.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);


    self.drawImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried drawing gradient for your colors?
This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883320/how-to-draw-cggradient-with-specific-color

Comment: Blending modes should be the right approach, but they only take effect between the lines and the background. You could try to draw the segments in separate steps, so that the lines already drawn belong to the image. Don't sure if this would help.